# Information added by Drupal.org on Distribution

Tags: distributions

Hi am trying to make a Drupal 8 Distribution, all is well, but when I download it from drupal.org I get on all modules this information.

I would like that all contrib modules to have their default information. What do I need to setup in order to remove the profile package from contrib modules?

In the image below Drupal.org comment out the module information and added profile information. I do not want to add the profile information on to the contrib modules.

```
# core: '8.x'
# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2017-08-15
# version: '8.x-1.0'
# core: '8.x'
# project: 'ace_editor'
# datestamp: 1502816349

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2018-01-18
version: '8.x-1.x-dev'
core: '8.x'
project: 'myprofile'
datestamp: 1516303995
```

So it's not confusing I don't want to remove the information from Drupal.org. Somehow Drupal.org is packaging the modules as part of the profile, and the result is the image below
[image]

I want to be able to see it normally like the image below
[image]

Comment: You'll have to script something manually as part of your workflow, maybe in the distribution's composer.json. I'd strongly recommend that you don't, though, people won't be very happy to use your distribution if they're not going to get notified of necessary updates to contrib modules (which the update module uses that info for). I rather doubt that would get past the security advisory either

Comment: I've updated my post so it's not confusing. I don't want to remove the information. Because Drupal.org is adding 'project: 'myprofile'' to all modules in the distribution I get them as part of the same update. What I would like is to get them like in a normal install.

Answer (score -1):

Whoever is getting the same error it is probably you got some patches and themes that are not from Drupal.org

The 2 links below helped me see what my problem was:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/packaging-a-distribution/how-to-package-a-distribution-on-drupalorg

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/packaging-a-distribution/drupalorg-distribution-packaging-requirements